# How to Stop The existing Url is Not open the Different Tab in the Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am Using Asp net mvc Application ..the Application Running Fine ..But the Problem is After Login the application it showing Some pages  i.e .cshtml page  . Here My Question Is When I Copy the Same Application Url Open in Different Tab Again it Should be ask the Login Page Again....

Comment: it Should be ask the Login Page Again?? really, is that your scenario ?? please guide what type of your app then may be i can help

Comment: Yes.Exactly...again it should be ask the Login Page..I don't want to  Allow the Application url not open in two tabs in the browser ..when ever tried like this .again it should be ask the Login page

Comment: Your application is SPA? Right

Comment: no it is normal web application using asp.net mvc

Comment: I want to check  if the user has already opened my website in another tab in their browser .if it is open then again it should ask the login page

Comment: where you're storing the data, when user is login into your website. i.e name, user name etc?

Comment: in Session i am storing the user credentials

Comment: Use forms to transfer the session instead of an cookie. That said, you probaby shouldn't. It hurts usability!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be done client side since the request to the server will not contain the information needed for this. You can use session storage to determine if the user went through the login screen. ("LogInTab" can be replaced with whatever you want to call the key in session storage) Put this java script in the login view.

```
<script>window.sessionStorage.setItem("LogInTab", "true");</script>
```

and this on each of the views that need to send the user back to the login screen if they copy the URL to a new tab (just use whatever the url is to the login page)....

```
<script>
    if (!window.sessionStorage.LogInTab)
    {
        window.location.href = '/Home/Index';
    }
</script>
```

putting it into a layout may be a good idea too

Answer (score -1):

Get an unique session in each browser tab [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331609/Get-an-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab)